# python script giving typerror on nested if statements

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a simple multiplication program first time in python and I get the following error, not sure why. My code is also posted below.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    from math import *

    def main():
        multiplier = raw_input('multiplier?')
        multiplicand = raw_input('multiplicand?')
        print (recursive(multiplier, multiplicand))

    def recursive(multiplier, multiplicand):
            if (multiplier == 0):
            answer = 0
        if (multiplier == 1):
            answer = multiplicand
        if ((multiplier > 1) & ((multiplier % 2) == 0)):
            answer = recursive((multiplier/2), (multiplicand*2))
        if ((multiplier > 1) & ((multiplier % 2) == 1)):
            answer = (multiplicand + (recursive((multiplier/2), (multiplicand*2))))
        return answer

    main()
```

Error:

```
multiplier?5
multiplicand?5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./multiplication.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "./multiplication.py", line 7, in main
    print (recursive(multiplier, multiplicand))
  File "./multiplication.py", line 14, in recursive
    if ((multiplier > 1) & ((multiplier % 2) == 0)):
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplier is a string so the modulus operator is attempting to put a value in the string here like you'd see in a string `string = "%s%d..."`. Hence the conversion error. Instead of a doing a `mod` operation. You need to convert the variable `multiplier` to an int (or float).

Comment: but i'm entering in a number '5'

Comment: Right, even if the number is a digit / integer. You still need to convert it because any variable set using `input` is itself a string.

Answer (score 0):

`multiplier` is being passed as a string, not a number. This is because `raw_input()` always returns a string. To convert it, do `float(raw_input())`.

The error is because the % operator returns the remainder for two numbers, but your string isn't a valid format string.

```
7 % 2 == 1
```

but it does string formatting when the first one is a string

```
'%d dogs ' % 2 == '2 dogs'
```